# MVC update second table

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller

I'm trying to add a "history" in a different table when my edit page submits changes to a "records" table. I want to save the record ID, the date, the user's ID and a delineated list of the old values that were changed (the column name, what they changed from and what they changed to).

So far, the basic controller is:

```
// GET: Record/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    TM_Records tM_Records = db.TM_Records.Find(id);
    if (tM_Records == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.Consult_Type = new SelectList(db.TM_Consult_Types, "TM_Consult_Type_ID", "TM_Consult_Type_Name", tM_Records.Consult_Type);
    ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.TM_Departments, "Dept_ID", "Dept_Name", tM_Records.Department);
    ViewBag.FSC = new SelectList(db.TM_FSCs_dim, "TM_FSC_ID", "TM_FSC_NAME", tM_Records.FSC);
    ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(db.TM_Genders_dim, "TM_Gender_ID", "TM_Gender_Name", tM_Records.Gender);
    return View(tM_Records);
}

// POST: Record/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Index_key,Hospital,NMXS_Consult_ID,DateTime_Requested,DateTime_Answered,DateTime_Completed,Patient_Name,DOB,MRN,Requesting_Provider,Consulting_Provider,Duration_Minutes,Ready_to_Review,DateTime_Reviewed,Bill_To,Bill_Amount,Consulting_Provider_ID,Requester_NPI,DateTime_Billed,DateTime_Payment_received,Amt_Received,Reconcile_Exception_Amt,File_Location,Initial_Diagnosis,Final_Diagnosis,Date_Loaded,Date_Updated,Gender,FSC,Consult_Type,Rec_Notes,Department,Valid_Record,DateTime_Billed_Rpt_Run")] TM_Records tM_Records)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(tM_Records).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Consult_Type = new SelectList(db.TM_Consult_Types, "TM_Consult_Type_ID", "TM_Consult_Type_Name", tM_Records.Consult_Type);
    ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.TM_Departments, "Dept_ID", "Dept_Name", tM_Records.Department);
    ViewBag.FSC = new SelectList(db.TM_FSCs_dim, "TM_FSC_ID", "TM_FSC_NAME", tM_Records.FSC);
    ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(db.TM_Genders_dim, "TM_Gender_ID", "TM_Gender_Name", tM_Records.Gender);
    return View(tM_Records);
}
```

and I'm trying to add a new record to the TM_History table with the following details:

```
Columns:
TM_Hist_ID, (primary key)
TM_Hist_Record_ID, (the record that was modified)
TM_Hist_Date, (populate with now())
TM_Hist_Values, (changes e.g. Price: $320 >> $220 | Note: "" >> $100 coupon)
TM_Hist_Ident_ID (User.Identity.Name)
```

I have searched stackoverflow and haven't been able to find anything with an answer applicable to this question.

Thanks for your consideration.

Robert

Comment: I don't even know what your question is. What's your issue?

Comment: How do I add a new record to the TM_History table with this information in the processing of the record change?

Comment: Have you investigated Change Tracking in SQL Server? There may not be a need to roll your own. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Dave R: End users that don't interact with the SQL server will need to be able to see the information, does Change Tracking in SQL Server accommodate that?

Comment: Apparently SQL Server's change tracking has some limitations that my DB admin says will not let us use it for this particular application. It's a cool thing to know about though.

Comment: @DaveR.I just figured out how to tag someone. Thank you for your insight, but unfortunately I have to "roll my own" in this case.  Any suggestions?